# HTML Scrolling Issue (I want to get rid of the buttons, horizontal option, and leave the snapping on)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollview

I would like to have a cool scroll effect that locks each div id on the page, but I am not sure how to. Here is what it looks like https://test.iamnotregis.repl.co/ -_-

I deleted the css because it is not needed but I will still link the project on repl.it https://repl.it/@IAmNotRegis/test#index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <!-- Load user defined styles -->
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="script.js"></script>

    <div id="carousel" class="snap">
      <div id="carousel-1">Item 1<br>Start scrolling ...</div>
      <div id="carousel-2">Item 2</div>
      <div id="carousel-3">Item 3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="controls">
      <button onclick="toggleSnap()">Turn Snapping <span id="otherSnappingState">off</span></button>
      <button onclick="toggleDirection()">Change scroll to <span id="otherScrollState">vertical</span></button>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

    function toggleSnap() {
      var snapEnabled = document.getElementById('carousel').classList.toggle('snap');
      document.getElementById('otherSnappingState').innerText = snapEnabled ? 'off' : 'on';
    }

    function toggleDirection() {
      var isVertical = document.getElementById('carousel').classList.toggle('vertical');
      document.getElementById('otherScrollState').innerText = isVertical 
    }

    #carousel {
      /* Ensure that the contents flow horizontally */
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: flex;
    }

    #carousel.vertical {
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    /* 2018 spec - For Safari 11, Chrome 69+ */
    #carousel.snap {
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Needed to work on iOS Safari */
    }

    #carousel.snap > div {
      scroll-snap-align: center;
    }

    #carousel.snap.vertical {
      flex-direction: column;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }



    /* 2015 spec - For Firefox, Edge, IE */
    #carousel.snap {
      scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
      scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
      -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
    }

    #carousel.snap.vertical {
      scroll-snap-points-x: initial;
      -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: initial;
      scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
      -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "controls" div from your index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <!-- Load user defined styles -->
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      

    <div id="carousel" class="snap">
      <div id="carousel-1">Item 1<br>Start scrolling ...</div>
      <div id="carousel-2">Item 2</div>
      <div id="carousel-3">Item 3</div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

The javascript functions  toggleSnap() and  toggleDirection() you dont need anymore you can remove them too.

But the styles.css file is mandatory. The CSS styles ensure that the snap magic kicks in.

```
#carousel {
  /* Ensure that the contents flow horizontally */
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

#carousel.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* 2018 spec - For Safari 11, Chrome 69+ */
#carousel.snap {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Needed to work on iOS Safari */
}

#carousel.snap > div {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

#carousel.snap.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}



/* 2015 spec - For Firefox, Edge, IE */
#carousel.snap {
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
}

#carousel.snap.vertical {
  scroll-snap-points-x: initial;
  -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: initial;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
  -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
}


/* Below here is styling, not important for the actual example, just to make it look nice. No need to look down here! */

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#carousel > div {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#carousel-1 {
  background-color: #e34747;
}

#carousel-2 {
  background-color: #5ab92c;
}

#carousel-3 {
  background-color: #226de2;
}

#controls {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#controls button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

If you want it to scroll vertically, add that class "vertical" name to your "Carousel" div as well.

```
<div id="carousel" class="snap vertical">
```

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work the same :( I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. What is the difference between class "snap" and "snap vertical"? I see mandatory and initial but I just want the program to work the same way it initially did

Comment: If I try your example at (https://repl.it/@IAmNotRegis/test#index.html) right now it works for me. With the classes "snap" or "snap vertical" you can control the same thing what you did with the buttons. If you add class="snap" snapping is enabled and with class="vertical" the scrolling change from "left to right" to "top to bottom". And for example if you want you can combine them class="snap vertical" (Snapping enabled and Scroll direction ist top to bottom)

Comment: Thanks so much! I never change my code because I kept messing things up sadly. Is there any chance you can input what it should look like with "snap vertical" in the html code?? I tried different variations and kept messing it up unluckily

Comment: I forked your [test](https://repl.it/@JakobLmmle/test#index.html) and add the "vertical". Take a look.